# REACT ERROR <th> cannot appear as a child of <thead>. See (unknown) > thead > th

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I am working on a react - rails app and I keep getting this error in my console:

```
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <th> cannot appear as a child of <thead>. 
See (unknown) > thead > th.
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working..I want to use header (thead) for a table and it worked for someone else. I would put tbody but I need that for the actual body of the table.

here is my code for this table:

```js
React.DOM.table
  className: 'table table-bordered'
  React.DOM.thead null,
    React.DOM.th null, 'Description'
    React.DOM.th null, 'Actions'
  React.DOM.tbody null,
    for post in @state.posts
      React.createElement Post, key: post.id, post: post, 
      handleDeletePost: @deletePost
```

**EDIT
I have tried adding the tr tag under thead and that causes an extra added error. this is what I changed my code to:

```js
React.DOM.table
  className: 'table table-bordered'
  React.DOM.thead null
    React.DOM.tr null
      React.DOM.th null, 'Description'
      React.DOM.th null, 'Actions'
    React.DOM.tbody null,
      for post in @state.posts
        React.createElement Post, key: post.id, post: post, 
        handleDeletePost: @deletePost
```

and the next error I get is:

```
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): tr cannot appear as a child of table. See (unknown) > table > tr. Add a <tbody> to your code to match the DOM tree generated by the browser.
```

I'm new to react and not familiar with coffeescript so I'm wondering if it has to do with the spacing or something. Tested out different spacing and that didn't help. I took out the thead all together and that caused my app to break so..not sure what's the problem

Comment: It should be `thead > tr > th`

Comment: I had typed `thread` instead of `thead`

Answer (score 186):

[The only direct children allowed for `thead` are `tr` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead), not `th`.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th />
    </tr>
  </thead>
  ...
</table>
```

Comment: I would've never expected React to teach me something about HTML!

Answer (score 97):

Well `th` should be nested under a `tr` not a `thead`. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead)

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>john</td>
      <td>33</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>smith</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>jane</td>
      <td>24</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I've tried adding tr to my code under thead but it gives me an extra error.

Comment: ```React.DOM.table
          className: 'table table-bordered'
          React.DOM.thead null
            React.DOM.tr null
              React.DOM.th null, 'Description'
              React.DOM.th null, 'Actions'
            React.DOM.tbody null,
              for post in @state.posts
                React.createElement Post, key: post.id, post: post, 
              handleDeletePost: @deletePost

Comment: i still then have my original error as well as "tr cannot appear as a child of table" and

Answer (score 4):

Mistakenly, I had `tbody` inside `thead`

(1)

```
<thead>
...
  <tbody>
  ...
  </tbody>
</thead>
```

instead of (2)

```
<thead>
...
</thead>

<tbody>
...
</tbody>
```

Changing to (2) solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this error come up because of mistakes elsewhere in my list.

For example @Sag1v has `<tbody>` instead of `</tbody>` to close the body of his list and I bet that is causing the error.

Answer (score 2):

Just put `<TableCell />` in to the `<TableRow />`

for example

```
import { Table, TableBody, TableCell, TableHead, TableRow } from '@mui/material';


export default function Untitled() {

  const items = GetItems() //get items from some where...

  return (
    <Table>
    <TableHead>
        <TableRow> // <--- I mean this section
            <TableCell> ID </TableCell>
            <TableCell> name </TableCell>
            <TableCell> last name </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
    <TableBody>
        {
            items.map((item, key) => (
                <TableRow key={key}> // <--- I mean this section
                    <TableCell> {item.id} </TableCell>
                    <TableCell> {item.name} </TableCell>
                    <TableCell> {item.last_name} </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
            ))
        }
    </TableBody>
</Table>
    );
}
```